# How do we allocate dynamic memory from shared memory?

Tags: c, shared-memory, matrix-multiplication

If I end up getting a pointer to shared memory of size mentioned in shmget. If that size is determined at run time . for example for a struct containing matrices which would be determined at runtime .I get a pointer to that struct. then how do I allocate memory for individual matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage shared memory yourself. You get a lump of it, then *you* have to parcel it up and hand it out and keep track of it yourself - or with some kind of handy library.